# How can I use flow monitoring software nload without installing it on Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm going to do some tests using nload, but I do not have the sudo rights to install the software on the cluster, I have already done the following processes:

```
$ wget http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/nload-0.7.4.tar.gz
$ tar xvf nload-0.7.4.tar.gz
$ cd nload*
$ sh ./configure
$ make
```

so what can I do next to run the software without using "make install"?

Comment: "*How do I install/use software X*" is not a programming question.

Comment: In general, you can usually pass options to `configure` to tell it where to install things, e.g. `./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr` or whatever.

Comment: I'm a total novice about Linux, and thank you for your useful comments!